# Every linear topological space embeds into the Tychonoff product of linear metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I need a reference to the following (known?)

> **Fact.** Every topological vector space $X$ over the field of real numbers is topologically isomorphic to a linear subspace of the Tychonoff product of linear metric spaces.

This seems to be a basic fact in the theory of topological vector spaces, but I did not find it in the classical textbooks: Bourbaki, Schaefer, Rolewicz, Robertson&Robertson. If you know a suitable reference, please help!

Comment: In other words, you claim that for every fixed neighborhood of $0$ in $X$ there is a continuous semi-metric on $X$ whose open ball is contained in that neighborhood. If I haven't made a stupid mistake somewhere, this is certainly true: just take a sequence of symmetric neighborhoods $U_k$  where $U_0$ is your original neighborhood and $(k+1)(U_{k+1}+U_{k+1})\subset U_k$ and declare the distance between $x$ and $y$ to be $\inf\{\sum_i 2^{-k_i}:x-y=\sum z_i, z_i\in U_{k_i}\}$. However (if I haven't made a mistake) it is rather a qualifier exam problem than a basic fact. Am I missing anything?

Comment: This fact should be true with a proof written by @fedja but with an extra-condition: $[-1,1]\cdot U_k\subset U_{k-1}$. Writing about "basic" fact, I did not have in mind that it is simple, but that it should be known and had to be included into basic textbooks dedicated to topological vectors spces.

Comment: It may be there in some form in the exercise sections, but who knows? Do you have any interesting corollaries you can derive from it? And yes, you are right: I was a bit sloppy when writing the conditions on $U_k$ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Jarchow's *Locally Convex Spaces* Theorems [2.7.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tYACAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39) and [2.9.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tYACAAAQBAJ&pg=PA43) on pages 39 and 43 together say that a *Hausdorff* topological vector space is linearly homeomorphic to a dense subspace of a projective limit of a projective system of metrizable topological vector spaces. Noting that in section 2.6 ([p. 37](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tYACAAAQBAJ&pg=PA37)) Jarchow defines *the* projective limit as a certain subspace of the product, this contains the required assertion *provided* that the space is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have it at hand but I would look at Köthe's book *Topological Linear Spaces*.

I believe that a proof can be given in the following way: For each $0$-neighbourhood $U$ choose a decreasing sequence of $0$-neighbourhoods $U_n$ with $U_0\subseteq U$, $U_n+U_n\subseteq U_{n-1}$ and $\lambda U_n \subseteq U_{n}$ for all $|\lambda|\le 1$. Then the topology $\tau_U$ on $X$ having $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as a basis of the $0$-neighbourhood filter is semi-metrizable by the Birkhoff-Kakutani theorem (at least Wikipedia tells it like that). Then $X$ is isomorphic to the diagonal in the product of all ($X,\tau_U)$. If $X$ is Hausdorff you can pass to the associated Hausdorff spaces $X_U$ of the $(X,\tau_U)$ by factoring out $\overline{\{0\}}^{\tau_U}$. If $q_U:X\to X_U$ is the quptient map you still get an embedding $X\to \prod_U X_U$, $x\mapsto(q_U(x))_{U}$. You can also take the completions of $X_U$ to make $X$ isomorphic to a subspace of the product of complete linear metric spaces.

EDIT. The result is contained in $3 (4) of the *Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics* 639, *Topological Vector Spaces* by Adasch, Ernst, and Keim.

Comment: This results seems to be absent in Kothe, too (if I have not missed anything). Of course the proof is more-or-less standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is wildly off topic but I couldn‘t resist giving the complete picture.
Every tvs (lcs, uniform space) is naturally isomorphic to a subspace of a product of $F$ spaces (complete metrisable ones) (Banach spaces, complete metric spaces).  Complete ones are isomorphic to closed subspaces in all three cases (an if and only if condition, of course). A tvs (lcs, uniform space) is emeddable as a closed subspace of a product of metrisable tvs‘s (normed spaces, metrisable spaces) if and only it satisfies a weaker completeness condition which I will make explicit in the case of uniform spaces——-a net $(x_\alpha)$ which satisfies the following condition is convergent: for each continuous semi-metric $d$ there is a $\gamma$ so that $d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)=0$ whenever $\alpha,\beta \geq \gamma$.

Comment: I think you mean $d(x_\alpha,x_\beta)<\varepsilon$ (for a given $\varepsilon$).

Comment: Of course I don‘t. That would make the third claim absurd

Comment: Ah, I see. I think you should give a reference.

Comment: user131781, I have doubts that I was right when deleting my question about compact sets in nuclear spaces. Would you like this question to be "undeleted" so that you could write an answer?

Comment: In the locally convex case, the condition can be reformulated as the completeness of the space considered as a topological *group* where a basis of the $0$-neighbourhoods is given by the *kernels* of continuous seminorms. This has been called *seminorm-kernel-completeness* in my *Derived Functors in Functional Analysis*.  The characterization *projective limit of normed spaces* $\Leftrightarrow$ *sk-completeness* is simple but nevertheless nice. I would be very interested in getting a reference for this little result.